# Uploading file with python to bottle server

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-upload, request, bottle

I've got two computers in the same network and I'm trying to pass a file from one to the other with python (in the context of a bigger project).

On the **server side** I've got the following bottle script:

```py
import bottle
import json

@bottle.hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    """
    You need to add some headers to each request.
    Don't use the wildcard '*' for Access-Control-Allow-Origin in production.
    """
    bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = '*'
    bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

# LANDING (IT IS NOT REALLY NEEDED JUST TO CHECK STUFF)
@bottle.route('/', method='GET')
def root():
    return {
        'api': 'api/'
    }

@bottle.route('/api', method='POST')
def upload():
    upload = bottle.request.files.get('file')
    print upload.filename
    upload.save('input.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

On the **client side** I'm trying to send the file through the request library such as:

```py
import sys
import requests

r = requests.post('http://ip:port/api/', files={'file': open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')})
print r
```

(*ip* and *port* corresponding to its respective values).

I am getting this error, which I'm not sure how to handle.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loopmatch.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.post('http://ip:port/api/', files={'file': open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 111, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 453, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem over there... Is should definitely work... Are you running behind proxy ? Try clean the pyc and close the pid if necessary and  make sure the ip port you run is free before running...

Comment: Everything looks alright on those regards. The *root* route was set to be able to evaluate those issues. I've seen what was the mistake. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... The thing is pretty silly... Just leaving the answer here in case someone else stomps with this stupid mistake...

The **bottle.route** and the **requests.url** need to match *exactly*. In may case, the **route** was `api` while the **url** was `api/`... this is why they were not working...

One needs to move both to `api/` or to `api`.

Comment: Cool.  FYI the reason they have to match exactly is because `/api` and `/api/` are *different* paths, according to the HTTP spec.  Considering them to be equivalent would be a serious problem in Bottle or any web framework.